# Navigating to the failed expect() from the ScalaTest window in IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

IDEA community + Scala Plugin and ScalaTest using FunSuite and expect style assertions.

The thing is when a test method fails, the plugin window just shows the me the failed method and the message generated by the expect() {} construct but does not provide me with any means to actually navigate to where the so called expect is located in the test code. I have to read the failure message (generated by the expect block) and deduce the block which caused the failure. any clues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation for failed and passed tests is not yet implemented, it seems.

I've added a [feature request in the IntelliJ bug tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/SCL-2655). Feel free to add your vote to it.